# Mallet Topic Modeling in Java

Tags: java, topic-modeling, mallet

What I find very hard with Machine Learning tutorials/books/articles is when a model is explained (even with code) you only get the code until you train (and/or test) the model. Then it stops. I cannot find tutorials/books starting from an example (eg topic modeling) where they start from a dataset, train the model AND show how you can use the model. In the code below, I have a dataset of news articles stored in folders per topic. Using Mallet I can create the model (and save it) but there it ends.

How can I use it now? Eg I feed the model an article and as an output it gives met the topic.
Please do not refer to the Mallet documentation as this also does not provide a full example from start till using the model.

Below an example taken from the book Machine Learning in Java (Bostjan Kaluza) where code is provide up to creating a model and saving/loading it. Great as a starting point for me but what if I want to use this trained model now.
Can somebody give an example in Java that goes all the way? It does not have to be with Mallet.

```
import cc.mallet.types.*;
import cc.mallet.pipe.*;
import cc.mallet.pipe.iterator.*;
import cc.mallet.topics.*;
import cc.mallet.util.Randoms;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TopicModeling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String dataFolderPath = "data/bbc";
        String stopListFilePath = "data/stoplists/en.txt";

        ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
        pipeList.add(new Input2CharSequence("UTF-8"));
        Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]+");
        pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(tokenPattern));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceLowercase());
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(new File(stopListFilePath), "utf-8", false, false, false));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());
        pipeList.add(new Target2Label());
        SerialPipes pipeline = new SerialPipes(pipeList);

        FileIterator folderIterator = new FileIterator(
                    new File[] {new File(dataFolderPath)},
                    new TxtFilter(),
                    FileIterator.LAST_DIRECTORY);
        
        // Construct a new instance list, passing it the pipe
        //  we want to use to process instances.
        InstanceList instances = new InstanceList(pipeline);

        // Now process each instance provided by the iterator.
        instances.addThruPipe(folderIterator);

        // Create a model with 100 topics, alpha_t = 0.01, beta_w = 0.01
        //  Note that the first parameter is passed as the sum over topics, while
        //  the second is the parameter for a single dimension of the Dirichlet prior.
        int numTopics = 5;
        ParallelTopicModel model = new ParallelTopicModel(numTopics, 0.01, 0.01);

        model.addInstances(instances);

        // Use two parallel samplers, which each look at one half the corpus and combine
        //  statistics after every iteration.
        model.setNumThreads(4);

        // Run the model for 50 iterations and stop (this is for testing only, 
        //  for real applications, use 1000 to 2000 iterations)
        model.setNumIterations(50);
        model.estimate();
        
        
        
        
        /*
         * Saving model
         */
        
        String modelPath = "myTopicModel";
        
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (new File(modelPath+".model")));
        oos.writeObject(model);
        oos.close();     
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (new File(modelPath+".pipeline")));
        oos.writeObject(pipeline);
        oos.close();     
        
        System.out.println("Model saved.");
        
        /*
         * Loading the model
         */
//      ParallelTopicModel model;
//      SerialPipes pipeline;
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (new File(modelPath+".model")));
        model = (ParallelTopicModel) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();   
        ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (new File(modelPath+".pipeline")));
        pipeline = (SerialPipes) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();   
        
        System.out.println("Model loaded.");
        

        // Show the words and topics in the first instance

        // The data alphabet maps word IDs to strings
        Alphabet dataAlphabet = instances.getDataAlphabet();
        
        FeatureSequence tokens = (FeatureSequence) model.getData().get(0).instance.getData();
        LabelSequence topics = model.getData().get(0).topicSequence;
        
        Formatter out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
        for (int position = 0; position < tokens.getLength(); position++) {
            out.format("%s-%d ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(tokens.getIndexAtPosition(position)), topics.getIndexAtPosition(position));
        }
        System.out.println(out);
        
        // Estimate the topic distribution of the first instance, 
        //  given the current Gibbs state.
        double[] topicDistribution = model.getTopicProbabilities(0);

        // Get an array of sorted sets of word ID/count pairs
        ArrayList<TreeSet<IDSorter>> topicSortedWords = model.getSortedWords();
        
        // Show top 5 words in topics with proportions for the first document
        for (int topic = 0; topic < numTopics; topic++) {
            Iterator<IDSorter> iterator = topicSortedWords.get(topic).iterator();
            
            out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
            out.format("%d\t%.3f\t", topic, topicDistribution[topic]);
            int rank = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext() && rank < 5) {
                IDSorter idCountPair = iterator.next();
                out.format("%s (%.0f) ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(idCountPair.getID()), idCountPair.getWeight());
                rank++;
            }
            System.out.println(out);
        }
        
        /*
         * Testing
         */
        
        System.out.println("Evaluation");

        // Split dataset
        InstanceList[] instanceSplit= instances.split(new Randoms(), new double[] {0.9, 0.1, 0.0});
        
        // Use the first 90% for training
        model.addInstances(instanceSplit[0]);
        model.setNumThreads(4);
        model.setNumIterations(50);
        model.estimate();
        
        // Get estimator
        MarginalProbEstimator estimator = model.getProbEstimator();
        double loglike = estimator.evaluateLeftToRight(instanceSplit[1], 10, false, null);//System.out);
        System.out.println("Total log likelihood: "+loglike);
}

}
/** This class illustrates how to build a simple file filter */
class TxtFilter implements FileFilter {

    /** Test whether the string representation of the file 
     *   ends with the correct extension. Note that {@ref FileIterator}
     *   will only call this filter if the file is not a directory,
     *   so we do not need to test that it is a file.
     */
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.toString().endsWith(".txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found it frustrating that ML packages sometimes forget about "production mode". That said, the most common use case for LDA is that you have a collection and you train on it. For inference for new documents you can always use the command line as described in the docs, but if you need a Java interface, you're probably going to have to put some examples together. The code you included supports loading a saved model, you would just need to use a [`TopicInferencer`](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/topics/TopicInferencer.java) instead of a `MarginalProbabilityEstimator`. Replace `getProbEstimator()` with `getInferencer()`. The source for [`TopicInferencer`](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/topics/TopicInferencer.java) has examples of processing an instance. You can use the `pipeline` object to import document strings into Mallet instance format. It would probably look something like

```
Instance instance = pipeline.pipe(new Instance(inputText, null, null, null);
double[] distribution = inferencer.getSampledDistribution(instance, 10, 0, 5);
```

(I have not tested this) The numbers are reasonable values for estimating posterior probabilities, but they are also rough guesses.